# Angular: Do you mock the dependencies of a controller when testing a directive?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a directive I am testing but it seems to want me to declare the dependencies of the controller the directive uses (ie. $modal, global ect) Is this something I need to do? If so how do you mock the dependencies for the controller when you are testing the directive? is it the same set up as mocking them for the controller?

The  error I get is:

> Test 'pbGoogleAnalyticsManagementList test:should call selectProfile()' failed
>       Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $modalProvider <- $modal <- GoogleAnalyticsManagementController

The test I am running is:

```
describe('pbGoogleAnalyticsManagementList', function () {
    var rootScope, scope, element;
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('pb.webSites.controllers'));
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('pb.webSites.directives'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile, $templateCache) {
        $templateCache.put('app/webSites/directives/GoogleAnalyticsManagementList.html', '<div></div>');
        rootScope = $rootScope;
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        element = angular.element('<pb-google-analytics-management-list data-pb-google-analytics-profile="webSite.googleAnalyticsProfile" data-pb-select-profile="addGoogleAnalyticsProfile(profile)">');
        $compile(element)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
    }));

    describe('test', function () {
        it('should call selectProfile()', function () {
            var elementScope = element.isolateScope();

            spyOn(elementScope, 'selectProfile');
            var data = {
                account: 'account',
                property: 'property',
                profile: 'profile'
            }

            elementScope.profileClick(data.account, data.property, data.profile);
            expect(elementScope.selectProfile).toHaveBeenCalledWith(data.account, data.property, data.profile);
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out you do need to include the Controller dependancies but in cases like mine that could get very out of hand. Since we are not testing the functionality of the controller you can use the $controllerProvider to create a new version of the Controller your Directive needs like this:

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('pb.webSites.controllers', function ($provide, $controllerProvider) {
        $controllerProvider.register('GoogleAnalyticsManagementController', function ($scope) {
            // Controller Mock
        });
    }));
```